# Entering if block that should not be entered

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a problem with the angularjs $location.
I have an auth interpreter which redirects to the login page if server returns 401 error (unauthorised).
I have put in app.js the auth interpreter and also in the app.js account data is loaded. This means that I have to make an if block before loading the account data because otherwise on the index screen it will try to load account data and the server will return unauthorised and will redirect to login screen; meaning i will never be able to go to index.html page.
Here is the if block:

```
if($location.path() != "/" 
   || $location.path() != "" 
   || $location.path() != "/register" 
   || $location.absUrl() != "http://localhost:8080/ipersonally/index.html")
```

So if I go to "localhost:8080/ipersonally/index.html#" or "localhost:8080/ipersonally/index.html#/" it takes me to the index page as it should. However if I got to "localhost:8080/ipersonally/index.html" it redirects me to login page. I think this must be because it enters the if block and tries to load account data. So I made:

```
console.log($location.absUrl());
```

Inside the if block. This returned in the browser console log "http://localhost:8080/ipersonally/index.html". **How can it enter the if block if I made
 `$location.absUrl() != "http://localhost:8080/ipersonally/index.html"`
in the if block?**
Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: What about the value of `$location.path()`? You use the `||` operator to create the condition value. It will enter the block when only one condition becomes true.

Comment: I did the `console.log($location.path())` and it was just a blank line in the console log. That's why i have the `$location.path() != ""`

Comment: Exactly. That's why `!="/"` becomes `true` and the loop is entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
if($location.path() != "/" 
   && $location.path() != "" 
   && $location.path() != "/register" 
   && $location.absUrl() != "http://localhost:8080/ipersonally/index.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your or condition "http://localhost:8080/ipersonally/index.html" is not equal to "/register" so the condition of your if-statement is fullfilled.